# install specific maven version in macos using brew

Tags: maven, installation

I am trying to install maven 3.6.3 by brew command but not working as  latest is maven 3.8.2

```
brew install maven
```

Any idea??

Comment: Why do you like to use an old Maven version? Use the most recent one...

Answer (score 1):

Most Homebrew formulae are named in such a way that the version is part of the formula's name. For example, `maven@3.5`.

Check out the specs for the `maven` formula: https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/maven.json. You'll find that `maven` has the alias `maven@3.8`. Usually, formulae without version numbers have an alias with the version number. However, `maven@3.8` is not its own package.

However, there are some versioned formulae. For example, `maven@3.5`, found [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/maven@3.5.json).

Long-story short, if you look at `versioned_formulae` in the `maven` formula, you'll find that there is no formulae for Maven 3.6. Not sure why because I am positive that it used to be.

You could try writing your own formula or downloading the specific version from the website: https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/.